# Testing breeze utilising jasmine

Tags: testing, jasmine, breeze

I am currently using the Jasmine testing framework and am fairly new to this.

I am trying to mock out the backend when so that well I call breeze's saveChanges I get some kind of mock response. Or maybe this is not quickest option.

I have tried using the spyOn($,'ajax') and subsequently expect($.ajax.mostRecentCall.args[0]["url"]).toEqual("/api/git/SaveChanges"). But unfortunately this is undefined error... there's something about breeze's saveChanges that does not seem to make an ajax call?

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'd like to provide some guidance for you. We're working on it but have none at the moment. Maybe you'll get there first. But you WILL have to learn to fake the XHR traffic and YES, the breeze `saveChanges` method ends up as an XHR POST.

The payloads in each direction are a bit complex but you can capture them from real traffic and tweak for your tests. At least that's how I'd begin.